# Format Sheets Cell based on ISFORMULA or Cell Type with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

new to coding and doing some Google Apps Script.

Trying to set some custom formatting for a large workbook to make things more readable and usable.

Is it possible to use Apps Script to set a color based on if the Cell is a formula?

I can't seen to find anything that using getBooleanCondition() or the ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder

Also can't seem to look for a Cell's Type using Apps Script.

Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Class Range Method get Formulas()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFormulas())

Answer (score 1):

**Set all formulas to green**

```
function setAllFormulasToGreen() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var f=rg.getFormulas();
  var b=rg.getBackgrounds()
  f.forEach(function(r,i){
    r.forEach(function(c,j){
      if(c){b[i][j]='green'}
    });
  });
  rg.setBackgrounds(b);//sets all backgrounds at one time
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper, could you explain how that loop works?

Comment: Have your read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)